# Applying an incremental function on dplyr::do() via group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have troubles applying dplyr::do() via group_by when calculating incrementally results for a sequence.

In a simplier case I could use for-loop:

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2002, 1), id = rep(letters[1], 3), obs1 = rep(1,3), obs2 = rep(1,3))

initialValue <- 5

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
initialValue[i+1] <- initialValue[i] + df$obs1[i] + df$obs1[i] 
}
```

So the output is the initial value followed by updated values for the years 2000:2002 in a list:

```
> initialValue
[1]  5  7  9 11
```

But I have loads of data from several years and several groups (ids). I believe dplyr::do() is the answer:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2002, 3), id = rep(letters[1:3], 3), obs1 = rep(1,9), obs2 = rep(1,9))
initialValue <- 5

doCalc <- function(obs){
initialValue <- initialValue + sum(obs)
}

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(new <- doCalc(obs = c(.$obs1, .$obs2)))
```

Error:

```
Error: Results 1, 2, 3 must be data frames, not numeric
```

What I expect is a tbl, for each group, a list of results from each year:

```
[[1]]
[1]  5  7  9 11

[[2]]
[1]  5  7  9 11

[[3]]
[1]  5  7  9 11
```

So how to apply this incrementially in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>% #assuming many groups are found in the original data
   mutate(val = list(accumulate(obs1, ~ .x + 2 *.y, .init = initialValue))) %>% 
  .$val
#[[1]]
#[1]  5  7  9 11

#[[2]]
#[1]  5  7  9 11

#[[3]]
#[1]  5  7  9 11
```

---

Or we can use `Reduce` from `base R`

```
unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$id), function(dat)  {
   dat$val <- list(Reduce(function(x, y) x + 2 *y, dat$obs1,
              accumulate = TRUE, init = initialValue))
   dat}), df$id)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2002, 1), id = rep(letters[1], 3), 
           obs1 = rep(1,3), obs2 = rep(1,3))
initialValue <- 5
```

Comment: Really nice clear examples, thanks! But I have troubles to implement this. My doCalc function will eventually do many tricks, involving matrix multiplication, and needs several variables from the data. I understood `purrr::accumulate()` and `Reduce()` take two arguments (x, y)? How to pass several arguments (variables) to the function?

Comment: @hermo It is based on your example and it works for that